Converting 2e characters to 5e, specifically magic items
I have been playing for quite a few years in 2e, and we have had the same party for about 12 years now; we don't play too often but are thinking about converting to 5e, and don't want start from the start again.
I've been looking into how I should convert characters, and there is a lot of good information about stats and skills etc., but I can't seem to find much on what to do with magic items, as they seem somewhat rarer in 5e and also behave differently.
One player has suggested that we choose 3-5 magic items and live with that, but I was wondering if anyone had other suggestions.
Also what to with dual class characters.
For clarity the party contains 7 characters, 3 which are dual class. All between 10th - 12th and have some very strong magic items now. We are also playing in Greyhawk and for anyone that is knowledgeable about that sort of stuff we have been playing through the War etc. and if there is any good starting off points for us in 5e.
Clarification and amplification
Thank you for your responses and comments.  I don't have the sheets with me at the current time so I may come back to it with more specific items.
But in general most characters have:
Magical enhanced armour classes whether it's rings/cloaks of protection or braces of AC, or +2 or above magical amour (depending on class).
Most are wearing 2 rings, like free action and fire resistance. One has a ring of vamp regen. And a ring of spell turning.
The warriors have boosted strength through a girdle or gauntlets.
The one mage has a heap of items from a broom and crystal ball to a familiar and many wands etc.
There are also a bunch of very specific magic items from specific modules, i.e. Tenser's castle, where the players get one of his self made magic items.
Magical weapons aren't actually the biggest deal, as the highest in the party is a +3 currently. But some of them do have some magical abilities.
All in all, including weapons and armour I'd say that most characters would have at least 8+ magic items each.
So I guess the question is; Do we try to find conversions for all of the magic items we have? or at current level will some of these be too rare or overpowered?
Sorry for the confusion, and I'll be mindful to try and be more precise in the future.

Narrowing the scope to specific magic items might make this easier to answer, especially if some of them are already published, under the same or updated names.

I'd specifically suggest something along the lines of "We have this list of magic items (from the Greyhawk setting if that's relevant) we'd like to replace with 5e equivalents, bearing in mind balance differences between the issues: <list, broken down by character>".

You should ask a separate question about which 5e publications discuss the War etc, and another separate question about how to convert dual class characters. Don't worry about having too many questions, everyone will be happy as long as each one is nice and clear.

Magic items are not only rarer (but that depends on the setting of course), they are less potent also: In 2nd edition the most powerful items had a +5 bonus, but in 5e the limit is +3 .

I don't think that converting items is an issue - converting characters is! 5e is completely different so even same classes play differently

Do you mean dual class (human, advance one class to X level and then swap over to a new one you stick to from there) or 2AD&D multiclass (not human, advance two classes simultaneously)?

I cleaned up some prose errors and formatting.  I think your additional info improved the question.

(I'm really only familiar with 2e from the '90s Baldur's Gate computer games, but from some initial research the base systems were fairly faithfully reproduced. I'll be using that base knowledge for this answer.)
At your current level, some items are almost guaranteed to be overpowered, and you definitely have more than you'll be able to use under 5e mechanics. Expect to narrow down what the party carries and leave some things behind.
Looking into what already has an existing version vs. what's no longer in the game will help you figure out which items might need to get left behind. We can go into more detail if you have a specific list of items, but this is a wide-view process for determining magic item translation.
Some recommended background.
Since you're asking about magic items in particular, I'm going to recommend four particular things to read through and think about in advance, to give you a sense of how 5e's treatment of power scaling math has shifted:

Thomas Markov's excellent answer discussing AC in 5e vs. a custom magic item from 2e that was being imported. The accompanying question and other answers are also great to read, but this one discusses in depth AC in a bounded accuracy environment and how just porting items that increase AC over without changes can end up more overpowered than they seem.

The Wizards of the Coast article on "Bounded Accuracy", which is the design philosophy underlying 5th edition's changes. While runaway ACs and DCs are, if memory serves, more common in the 3.x era, 2e warrior classes could hit some pretty insane THAC0 that nobody else could ever touch. This goes over the idea behind how 5e flattened the curve on power creep via class advancement; curbing item power levels also plays into this design philosophy.

The Monster Manual. Read through it, or pick a handful of monsters you know well and directly compare them. Can [X monster] hit your characters? Can your characters ever miss? General consensus is that CR calculations in 5e are rough, but it should give you a sense of what is expected to challenge a group of 4 characters at a given level.

The 2024 Dungeon Master's Guide, Treasure chapter. This is the biggest initial grouping of magic items for 5e. This will  give you a sense of how the power level of magic items has changed in this edition. This also where it's noted in a sidebar that 5e generally considers magic items, in paraphrase, a "nice to" not a "need to", giving additional power without being required to match a threat of the same level.


Note that +3 is the highest any AC bonus, attack bonus, or spell attack/save DC bonus can go in 5e, and items that grant those typically are rated "very rare", meaning you should just be starting to introduce one or two overall at character level 11.
Embrace "Attunement" and see what has a 5e version.
Attunement is described in depth in the 2024 Player's Handbook on p. 232, in the Equipment chapter. It is how 5e limits item-based power creep. Many magic items require attunement to gain their magical features (some by specific types of people), only one creature can attune to an item at a given time, and you can only attune to 3 items at once. Attuning takes a full short rest--1 hour, RAW--so you can't just swap things out on the fly.
Make a list of what has a 5e equivalent, and mark which of those things require attunement. (If you can find a good resource for them, check adventure books and expansion material as well, as many added new magic items.) It will be many of them: most wands of higher power than a 1st level spell now require attunement by a spellcaster, armor or weapons that have special abilities outside of flat bonuses, most non-consumable wondrous items Rare or better.
Leave off items without an official 5e version for now. Who now has more power than they can attune to at once? Using your question as a baseline, a warrior with rings of free action and fire resistance, plus gauntlets of ogre power is at his 3 item attunement cap. Did he have anything else requiring attunement? He can't use them all at once, so he now gets to pick what he keeps.
Who now has AC that strains bounded accuracy? Since bonuses in 2e range from +1 to +5, vs. 5e's +1 to +3, you may need to condense magic item bonuses to fit within 5e's range. Even if it's just the flat bonus and therefore doesn't require attunement, it will likely need tweaking to keep within the expected range of values. If anyone has +X armor and +X shield, you may need to reduce further since they stack.
Who has an item so changed they won't (or can't) use it anymore? Some items have been significantly changed--the ring of spell turning you mention, for example, functions quite differently in 5e, and is also considered a legendary item appropriate for level 15+!
On that note, who has items too rare for this level? This one's a bit more malleable since the rating system isn't well-defined, and may depend on how you want your world to feel, but it's meant to be a rough measure of how common (or not) a given magic item is in-setting. The 2024 PHB gave a new table on what starting equipment should be at higher levels; it recommends a maximum of 1 Rare, 2 Uncommon, and 2 Common magic items per character for starting at levels 11-16 (p.43). (This is also calibrated using Forgotten Realms, I believe, so discussing with someone who knows Greyhawk better is recommended here.)
You should probably not have any legendary items in the party at levels 10-12. Allowing one early can be used as a plot point, as valuable things gravitate towards owners who can hold them, but it can easily throw power balance out of whack to allow legendary power too early.
How many useable things does each character now have? Accounting for attunement limit, does anyone have far more or far fewer items than the rest of the group? This one will depend on your group, but if someone has ended up with a bunch more things they're keeping than everyone else, they might have to leave more things behind.
This will probably give you a decent range of items to start with in narrowing down the field, even without counting custom items or ones that don't have 5e versions. For items that don't have a direct 5e version, you have a choice. You can either remove them and avoid homebrew balance issues, or you can try to homebrew things. I highly, highly recommend asking friends or an online group experienced in 5e mechanics to help review anything you homebrew for balance.
Start small and scale up
It always feels better to get more than it does to get something taken away for being overpowered. Go through existing 5e to see what matches, and then see what that looks like in play. You may not get it right the first try, and that's okay--but you should make it clear to your players that there may need to be tweaks after some initial 'playtesting' of the new builds/items. Maybe run a 'non-canon' oneshot or two to let people try out the new builds, get used to the new system, and see how the new versions of the items play.
If the feel of the game still wants more magic items, then you can add in stronger, rarer, or homebrewed things to your taste. As long as you and your table are happy with the end result, then that's fine no matter how you run it.

This is a great answer, but a minor point that jumped out at me was that we do in fact have the 2024 Dungeon Master's Guide - D&D Beyond "Master Tier" subscribers have had access to it for a little while now.

@DaniO'Shea Well, that is a dubious use of "we" but fair enough.

@Thank-Glob it was intended as a slightly wry "we" in response to the collective "we" in the answer, for sure, but the subscription cost is about the same as the individual physical book, so in terms of "can anyone get access to it if they're prepared to buy it", I think it's more or less true.

@DaniO'Shea I don't use DDB, so I don't have a copy yet. Once I do have access to it, I'll see what changed and what needs updating.

Have a look at 5e conversions such as TftYP
Miss Misinformation's excellent answer is steeped in theory, and well explains the differences in intent between the different editions.  If you would like some practical examples of what this looks like on the ground, you can make comparisons with some modules that have been converted to 5e.  Since your characters have played in modules, in Greyhawk, it is likely that the ultimate sources of at least some of their items have been converted, which gives you a pretty good idea of how to represent them.  You might find the specific items themselves, but with enough searching, you are likely to find at least something similar.  Some items, particularly those that give plusses, have been rescaled.  Others have the same name, but their powers are different in first / second vs. fifth edition.
While most modules have a stand-alone 3rd party conversion, if not multiple ones, Tales from the Yawning Portal offers official conversions for nine adventures, six of which were originally in first edition1, so it is a great place to start (there is very little difference between magic items in first and second edition, as the table below will show).  Consider how one well-equipped NPC has fared across the editions:

 Obmi, from G3: Hall of the Fire Giant King




1e2
2e3
5e (TftYP)




Fighter / Thief 9/11
Fighter / Thief 9/11
Assassin (CR8)


Plate Armor +2
Plate Armor +2
Dwarven Plate


Shield +2
Shield +2
+1 Shield


Axe +1
Axe +1
+1 Battle Axe


Hammer +3
Hammer +3
+1 War Hammer


Gauntlets of Ogre Power
Gauntlets of Ogre Power
Gauntlets of Ogre Power


Ring of Invisibility
Ring of Invisibility
Ring of Invisibility





 1 Counting G1/2/3 as three modules, and as first edition
2 From G3
3 From GDQ1-7

